# Unique Levy Measure in Levy Khintchine Formula

Tags: stochastic-processes

The Levy-Khintchine formula gives a triple $(a,\sigma,\nu)$ for the characteristic exponent $\Psi(s)$ of an infinitely divisible random variable where

$\Psi(s)=ias + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2s^2 + \int_{\mathbb{R}}(1-e^{isx} + is\mathbb{1}_{|x|<1})d\nu(x)$

My question is whether $\nu$ is unique? Or whether it is only the unique Levy measure?

Are there references in the literature to this fact.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a one-to-one correspondance between infinitely divisble distributions and the triple $(a,\sigma,\nu)$ given by the Lévy-Khintchine formula. You can have a look at *Lévy Processes and Infinitely Divisible Distributions* by Ken Iti Sato (Theorem 8.1).

Comment: Thanks you. Is it possible that $\nu(x)$ is decreasing for certain values of x? Obviously this would imply that the random variable is not infinitely divisible.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking, since $\nu$ is a measure. What do you mean by decreasing?

Comment: Sorry if $\nu(x)$ is negative for certain x?

Comment: No, it's a measure, i.e. $\nu(A)\geq 0$ for every Borel set $A$.

Comment: So it is possible that there could exist a function $\nu_2(x)$ which satisfies the Levy-Khintchine characteristic exponent as given in the original post but is not a measure i.e. $\nu_2(x)<0$ for some $x$? While a unique measure $\nu_1(x)\geq0$ $\forall x\geq0$ may also exist?

Comment: Hello stefan, I am just wondering if you understand my question or if you are still there please? Thanks

Comment: I don't follow what you are asking. In the Levy-Khintchine setup $\nu$ is a measure and $d\nu(x)$ denotes integration with respect to the measure $\nu$. Writing $\nu(x)$ does not make any sense in the setup, because $\nu$ is function on the Borel sets of $\mathbb{R}$. Nevertheless, I have no idea whether this generalizes to $\nu$ being a signed measure (i.e. $\nu$ is allowed to be negative).

Comment: Thank you for your time Stefan. Yes I was curious whether $\nu$ could be a signed measure.